# Method overriding in python

Tags: python, methods, overriding

I only get one output that is multiply:6 but I want both outputs.

Why am I not getting a `return` value if I used `return` in `class` `Add`

```
class Add:
    def result(self, x, y):
        return f"add, a, b"

class multi(Add):
    def result(self, a, b)
        p=a*b
        super().result (1, 2)
        return f"multiply:{p}"


x=multi() 
print(x.result(2, 3))
```

I want 2 outputs together

```
add: 3
multyply:6
```

Comment: when i put print(f"add: {q}) instead of return(f"add: {q}) I get out out as i want... But i want to return not print.

Answer (score 1):

you can return and print where you are calling `super().result`

```
class Add:
  def result(self, x, y):
    return f"add => {x} + {y} = {x+y}"

class multi(Add):
  def result(self, a, b):
    print(super().result (1, 2))
    return f"multyply => {a} * {b} = {a*b}"


x=multi() 
print(x.result(2, 3))
```

Comment: thank you bhai.. But what if i don't add print(super(). result(1, 2)). I don't want to add print i want to return.

Comment: If you don't add print then returned thing will not be used anywhere and thatswhy you are not getting anything. As you can see when you are returning from multi then also you are printing that else it will not be printed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to print inside the function multi:

```py
class Add:
    def result(self, x, y):
        return f"add:{x+y}"


class multi(Add):
    def result(self, a, b):
        p=a*b
        add = super().result (1, 2)
        return add+"\n"+f"multiply:{p}"


x=multi() 
print(x.result(2, 3))
```